# Android studio takes too long to open

Tags: performance, android-studio, windows-10

When I click the android studio icon on my desktop, its takes more than 5-10 minutes or even more to open android studio window.

Then the Gradle build also takes too long to refresh although I have set offline mode 'on'. and if i sync the project it takes way too long again

I have i5 processor with 6gb RAM running windows 10 and I use Genymotion as online device to debug and run my application.

Please help, it takes way too long and a lot of time is wasted

Comment: But you have HDD. Android Studio and Visual Studio take more than one minute to load even on SSD.

Comment: have you check the memory usage?. This could be a problem from the windows 10 itself. Maybe my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38004831/4758255 could help you.

Comment: i don't know what is the problem. visual studio is working good and opens on time. but android studio does not even open on time when I click the icon.

Comment: I just did what you referred but still android studio is not opening, it has been more than five minutes now  @ישואוהבאותך

Answer (score 1):

This is happening in Android Studio 2.0 or > 2.1. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37498254/2462531) answer you need to uncheck the Instant Run option.

> Settings/Preferences(Mac) → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Instant Run